# DropDown with Enum - Value attribute for Select

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, enums, html-helper

I am having following `DropDown` which populates from `Enum`.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Month1, Enum.GetNames(typeof(Models.InputMonths)).Select(e => new SelectListItem { Text = e }), "--Select Month--", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "Month1" })

public enum InputMonths
{
    January = 1,
    February = 2,
    March = 3,
    April = 4,
    May = 5,
    June = 6,
    July = 7,
    August = 8,
    September = 9,
    October = 10,
    November = 11,
    December = 12
}
```

The output of html is like this `<option>January</option>`

I want `value` of the month in `numeric` like this `<option value="1">January</option>`

How will the `value` attribute come with numeric values?

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify `Value` in `new SelectListItem { Text = e, Value = enumValue }`

**EDIT**

```
List<InputMonths> months = Enum.GetValues(typeof(InputMonths)).Cast<InputMonths>().ToList();
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Month1, months.Select(e => new SelectListItem { Text = e, Value = (int)e }), "--Select Month--", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "Month1" })
```

Comment: Shows me error  `CS0103: The name 'enumValue' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: It's just example. You have to specify your own variable.